# How to always draw a child mesh in front of its parent mesh

Tags: unity, rendering, 3d-meshes, depth-buffer

I need to display a gizmo-like mesh at runtime, and it must be always in front of its target mesh. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Presumably you tried disabling the depth test in the gizmo's material, and drawing it after your target mesh?

Comment: Yes, but it's only a visual effect, I can't get things like MonoBehaviour.OnMouseEnter(), for example.

Comment: That's a different question than the one you asked above, which says "draw" and "display", not "pick". Picking has alternative solutions, like firing your own raycast that ignores the parent's layer, or adding an extra, invisible collider in front of the parent, etc. Please edit your question to be sure it accurately reflects what you need and what you've tried / where your remaining problems lie.